# MS SQL, How to ALTER/ CREATE procedure with error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need create procedure with contain errors. For example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.test
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT *
    FROM openquery(LINKED, 'select * from something'' ')
END
GO
```

Could not find server 'LINKED' in sys.servers

How can I created it though any errors (Not exists linkedserver or select in openquery return error) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic SQL to avoid linked server validation. Now you'll get the linked server error on execution instead of compilation. I personally think dynamic SQL is not an elegant solution, but it solves your problem.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.test
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @sqlCommand NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT *
        FROM openquery(LINKED, ''select * from something'''' '')';

    EXEC (@sqlCommand)
END
GO
```